# How to align both words to start from the same column

Tags: html

I have the following code:

```
<center>
<div>
    first
    <br />
    second
</div>
</center>
```

I want to leave the text at the center, but i need to align both words to start from the same column.

How can i do it?

Comment: You can't center the text while also having two words start at the same alignment. At least not using ``<center>``. Besides, ``<br>`` will do instead of ``<br />``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left">
    first<br />
    second
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
<div align="center>
<div style="float:left; text-align:center;">First</div>
<div style="float:left; text-align:center;">second</div>
</div>
```